# Not common filtering in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

Have some row set with next data

```
s1  in1  out1  t1  date1
s2  in2  out2  t2  date2
...
si  ini  outi  ti  datei
```

The table structure is:

```
s1    BIGINT PK 
in
out
t     BIGINT 
date  DATETIME
```

where date - date with time when session start, and time - how long will the session (in seconds). 
I need filtering in query with this condition:

```
row write to the result set if:

    datei+1-datei<ti
```

It's because DB table have some amount corrupted rows.
I can make this programmatically. But is it possible to make this in MySQL query?
Most interesting are row offset.

**UPDATE**
When I say  `datei+1` - it's mean date from next row (offset by index)

Comment: Can you show the table structure? I mean what is the column types?

Comment: s1 - BIGINT PK, in,out,t -BIGINT, date - DATETIME

Comment: When you say datei+1. Do you want to increase `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `MINUTES`, `SECONDS` or `MILISECONDS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right. You might what something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
        Table1.s1,
        Table1.date,
        Table1.t,
        (
        SELECT
           MIN(tbl.s1) AS s1
        FROM
           Table1 AS tbl
        WHERE 
            tbl.s1 > Table1.s1
        ) as NextId
    FROM
        Table1
) AS tblInner
JOIN Table1 AS Next
    ON tblInner.NextId=Next.s1
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Next.date,tblInner.date)<tblInner.t
```

**References:**

- [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql)
- [TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)