# fetching consecutive records using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a student record table with `rollno` as id how can i get the first,previous,next,last records on button click from the database using ***php***

i used `$rollno+1` for next record and `$rollno-1` for previous record

When a `rollnum` is missing then it should go for the next or previous record

For example : i have rollnums like this 1,2,3,5,6.....

When my roll num is 3 when i click next it should display the next record that is record with `rollno` num 5 how can i get this similarly for the previous record

Help me with this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

***Unable to post in comments. So posting Here***

Can you put something thay you had tried. A piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

**USE LIMIT**

```
$rollnext=$roll+1;
$rollprev=$roll-1;

SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit $rollnext,1
SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit $rollprev,1
```

eg:
current page:2

next: 3
previous:1

```
SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 3,1
SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 1,1

record 1: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 0,1
record 2: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 1,1
record 3: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 2,1
record 4: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 3,1
record 5: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 4,1
record 6: SELECT * FROM `records` order by `rollnum ` limit 5,1
```

and so on

Comment: if i dont have a record with the rollno 3 it should return record with rollnum 4