# Mysql: Group rows with same value until the value is changed

Tags: mysql

My table look like this:

```
   |ID| |Userid|    |ItemId|
    10        1            10
     9        1             9
     8        1             8
     7       38             7
     6       38             6
     5       38             5
     4        1             4
     3        1             3
     2        1             2
     1        1             1
```

My sql  request is:

```
SELECT *
FROM nfeeds n1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT friendId
    FROM friends f WHERE friendId = n1.userid AND f.userid = 'my_userid')
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And result is:

```
|ID|    |Userid|    |ItemId|
10        1            10
 7       38             7
```

I would like the result  like this:

```
|ID|    |Userid|    |ItemId|
10        1            10
 7       38             7
 4        1             4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does id always equal item_id? How convenient!

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking, please explain

Comment: ...and is id always contiguous?

Comment: yes, i want to select the last id of same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This assumes contiguous ids (no gaps)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Userid INT NOT NULL
,ItemId INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10 ,1,4),
(9  ,1,9),
(8  ,1,3),
(7 ,38,7),
(6 ,38,2),
(5 ,38,1),
(4  ,1,5),
(3  ,1,8),
(2  ,1,6),
(1  ,1,9);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT MIN(c.id) id 
         FROM my_table a
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table b 
           ON b.userid = a.Userid 
          AND b.id = a.id - 1 
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table c 
           ON c.Userid = a.userid
          AND c.id >= a.id
         LEFT
         JOIN my_table d
           ON d.Userid = a.userid
          AND d.id = c.id + 1
        WHERE b.id IS NULL 
          AND c.id IS NOT NULL
          AND d.id IS NULL
        GROUP 
           BY a.id
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id; 
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | Userid | ItemId |
+----+--------+--------+
|  4 |      1 |      5 |
|  7 |     38 |      7 |
| 10 |      1 |      4 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffc8e1/1

Answer (score 2):

MySQL offers a pretty efficient way to do this, using variables.  The more efficient solution doesn't use a temporary table or any joins.  Here is a method assuming that you want the maximum user id and item id for each group (it is unclear whether you want the max or the first value):

```
select max(id) as userid, max(item_id) as item_id
from (select n.*,
             (@grp := if(@u = userid, @grp,
                         if(@u := userid, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) grp
      from nfeeds n cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @u := -1) vars
      order by id desc
     ) n
group by grp, userid;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do you have table `nfeeds` which contains sequences of records *done by different users* (in your example sequence `10,9,8` by user 1, `7,6,5` by user 38 and sequence `4,3,2,1` again by user 1). And you want to select *the latest* record for each sequence.

I would go with one more relation table  `sequences (id, user_id, max_nfeeds_id)`, but lets stay with your example.

You want to have condition based on previous row but *AFAIK* MySQL doesn't offer any straight forward solution to do this. But...

[You can join record with next id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446831/1149736) and compare user IDs.

```
SELECT nfeeds.*
FROM nfeeds
LEFT JOIN nfeeds AS nfeeds_prev ON nfeeds_prev.id = (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM nfeeds AS nfeeds_inner 
    WHERE nfeeds_inner.id > nfeeds.id)
WHERE nfeeds_prev.userId IS NULL
    OR nfeeds.userId != nfeeds_prev.userId
```

The `IS NULL` part is there for case that `nfeeds_inner` returns `NULL`  (first record).

*I doubt you will be able to take advantage of indexes with this and you WILL always end up with [`Using Where`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) going trough all rows.*