# Mysql query for searching keyword

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a search keyword and I am searching for that keyword using two tables.

The search keyword is 'Patient'

Table -    default_pages

```
id        type_id     parent_id         status
68        16          0                 draft
70        17          68                live
227       17          44                live
262       1           31                live
```

Table -    default_search

```
id       title                 entry_id
1        patient status        70
2        patient check         227
3        patient health        262
```

My query is

```
"SELECT 
            s.title, p.id, p.type_id AS sqem 

            FROM default_search s LEFT JOIN default_pages p ON p.id=s.entry_id  

            WHERE s.title LIKE '%Patient%' 

            HAVING sqem IS NOT NULL"
```

The above query returns 3 results where the ids from default pages are 70, 227, 262 but the problem is for the id 70, it's parent id is 68 and the status of id 68 is draft so I want to exclude this row from the result set and this is where I am stuck.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check for status in your `default_pages` table:

```
SELECT 
s.title, p.id, p.type_id AS sqem 
FROM default_search s LEFT JOIN default_pages p ON p.id=s.entry_id  
WHERE s.title LIKE '%Patient%' AND p.status='live'
HAVING sqem IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It returns the same 3 rows. But I don't want 70 to be included in the results because it's parent has got 'draft' status.

Comment: I think you should look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446831/3067928 and modify your query according to that. Why don't you create sqlfiddle. So, other can also try on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    s.title, p.id, p.type_id AS sqem 
    FROM default_search s LEFT JOIN default_pages p ON p.id=s.entry_id
    LEFT JOIN default_pages dp ON p.parent_id = dp.id
    WHERE s.title LIKE '%Patient%' AND p.status='live' AND dp.status='live'
    HAVING sqem IS NOT NULL
```

Another Left join with default_pages "connecting" parent_id with id ?