# MySQL query to get next record if exists else 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure in MySQL for which I have to write code

```
 id  Docid  deptid 
-------------------
 1   Doc1  dept1
 2   Doc2  dept1
 3   Doc3  dept2
 4   Doc4  dept2
 5   Doc5  dept2
```

I have to write a query to get `Docid` in a sequential manner for the above MySQL structure in such a way that when client approach `dept1`, which has 2 `Docid`s – `Doc1` and `Doc2`. When a client approach `dept1` for the first time it should direct him to `Doc1` first and then to `Doc2`, and if he again wants to approach `dept1` for more Docs then code again redirect it to `Doc1` and vice versa.

The same should happen for `dept2`, which has 3 `Docid`s – `Doc3`, `Doc4` and `Doc5`. If the client approaches `dept2` for the first time, then MySQL should direct it to `Doc3` first, then to `Doc4` and last to `Doc5`. If the client has approached all the Docs in `dept2`, he should be directed again to `Doc3` and the whole cycle goes again whenever client approaches `dept2`.

I am not getting how to write a query or restructure my table columns so that I can get next `Docid` each and every time when I execute select query by filtering department wise.

Please guide me to restructure and write MySQL query for this case.

Thank you for all your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Akansha what you have tried yet?

Comment: why don't you use `order by Docid asc` with your SQL query

Comment: I'm managing in another table to save doctor Ids in department wise for which user is visited

and by using this, i'm trying to get next doctor Ids

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql

Comment: order by clause will give all the results i need a single row each and every time i execute a query in a sequential manner as described above.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a deptdocid column using row number simulation
for example given this

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, Docid varchar(10), deptid varchar(10));
insert into t values 
( 1 ,  'Doc1',  'dept1'),
( 2 ,  'Doc2',  'dept1'),
( 3 ,  'Doc3',  'dept2'),
( 4 ,  'Doc4',  'dept2'),
( 5 ,  'Doc5',  'dept2'); 

ariaDB [sandbox]> select t.*,
    -> if(t.deptid <> @p , @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) deptdocid,
    -> @p:=t.deptid
    -> from (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn, t
    -> order by t.deptid, t.id;
+------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
| id   | Docid | deptid | deptdocid | @p:=t.deptid |
+------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
|    1 | Doc1  | dept1  |         1 | dept1        |
|    2 | Doc2  | dept1  |         2 | dept1        |
|    3 | Doc3  | dept2  |         1 | dept2        |
|    4 | Doc4  | dept2  |         2 | dept2        |
|    5 | Doc5  | dept2  |         3 | dept2        |
+------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and if we have

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from drdept;
+------+------+--------+---------+
| id   | dr   | deptid | visitno |
+------+------+--------+---------+
|    1 | abc  | dept1  |       1 |
|    2 | abc  | dept2  |       3 |
|    3 | def  | dept1  |       2 |
+------+------+--------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then joining drdept to the deptdocid should give us what we want

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select dr.dr,dr.deptid,dr.visitno,s.deptid,s.docid,s.deptdocid
    -> from drdept dr
    -> left join
    -> (
    -> select t.*,
    -> if(t.deptid <> @p , @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) deptdocid,
    -> @p:=t.deptid
    -> from (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn, t
    -> order by t.deptid, t.id
    -> ) s on s.deptid = dr.deptid and s.deptdocid = dr.visitno;
+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| dr   | deptid | visitno | deptid | docid | deptdocid |
+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
| abc  | dept1  |       1 | dept1  | Doc1  |         1 |
| abc  | dept2  |       3 | dept2  | Doc5  |         3 |
| def  | dept1  |       2 | dept1  | Doc2  |         2 |
+------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Clearly you need to maintain the drdept table and the visitno but after that it's pretty straightforward.