# next row from mysql using sql Query

Tags: mysql

My current query is

```
SELECT p.* FROM proxies p where p.last_used=1
```

here in db, according the query select id=4 but i want to select next record 
wheer id=5
(For details please click on image)
[image: next row from mysql using sql Query]

need help

Comment: "next record" is subjective, it depends on the ordering of the data. The order it appears when just browsing through phpmyadmin is not something to rely on - database engines don't store data in any particular order (or at least, that ordering is not guaranteed). What exactly is the criteria that makes id 5 the "next" row? e.g. is the formula to look at the id of the "last used" row and increment id by 1? Or just get the next highest id? Or something else? what if a row is deleted in the meantime?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql , it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT p.id FROM proxies p where p.id >
(SELECT p.id FROM proxies p where p.last_used=1 LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY p.id 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry - you are right - i will add it in my answer (sorry)

Comment: There's still a LIMIT there without an ORDER BY !!