# MySQL: How do I select the next or previous row from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a table called "`posts`", and within that table a column with "`post_id`" (A long with other columns ofc).

How to I select the next (or previous) row from the table, by "`post_id`"?

Let's say my current "`post_id`" is 15. Now I need to select the next row, where certain conditions are met, so I need to put in some where clauses.

I'm bad at explaining this I feel. I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT (next row) FROM posts WHERE post_draft=0 && post_approved=1
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: In a database there is no `next` or `previous` row.

Comment: Make new variable $previous = $post_id-1; And then make query to select where id=$previous. Also, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql

Comment: Also, make sure you clean up your query before using it. PDO the shit out of it so you always have a solid base protection.

Comment: @NikolayGanovski - `$post_id-1` won't work when there are gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational database system have no concept of a "next row" or "previous row". That is because there is no natural order of entries in such a database. So there terms "next" and "previous" are not really defined.

You can however implement a query that delivers what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE post_id>15 
    AND post_draft=0 
    AND post_approved=1
  ORDER BY post_id ASC
  LIMIT 1;
```

So if you have the *current* `post_id` it is easy to pick the "next" entry according to a given order of a result set. The same is obviously possible for the "previous" entry.

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm. To select the previous row I just changed post_id greater than, to lesser than, and ORDER BY to DESC, if anyone else stumbles upon this post one day :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this.

```
$next_post_query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_draft`=0 AND `post_approved`=1 AND `post_id` > {$current_post_id} order by `post_id` asc limit 1";
$prev_post_query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_draft`=0 AND `post_approved`=1 AND `post_id` < {$current_post_id} order by `post_id` desc limit 1";
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the post_id column is auto-increment, you can try

`select * from posts where post_id in (select post_id+1 from posts where post_draft=0 and post_approved=1)`

Comment: `$post_id+1` won't work when there are gaps.  Nor will that subquery work if the next id is a draft or not approved.

Comment: @RickJames Hello!!! I assumed post-id is auto-increment so there's unlikely to be any gaps...

Comment: @RickJames : Secondly my assumption of the question: he wants to select the 'next' post-id after the 'post-id' that satisfies the where condition...

Comment: @RickJames So... if post_id=1 where draft=0 and post_approved=1... then we want to display the row for post id=2.. similarly if post_id=5 where draft=0 and post_approved=1... then we want to display the row for post id=6

Comment: @RickJames I think my answer satisfies the requirement... but maybe I understood the question wrong...

Comment: Wow.  Upon second look...  That's a correlated IN-SELECT!  That is one of the more contorted constructs I have seen in a long time -- It checks each post_id for the next one having the correct filtering.  So, perhaps my criticism of gaps is not right.  Still, there is no mention of `15` or `limit 1`.  Once they are added, I don't think the query can survive in its current format.

Comment: (We both knew a Logan?)

Comment: @RickJames :: I don't see why do we need a 15 here... 15's just a sample given by the questioner. He needed a generic result.

Comment: I'm not the only Rick James; you are not the only Krishna Kumar.  It's a big world.  We both worked for a Logan.

Comment: The Question asks how to find the "next" one, and uses "15" as a sample.  I would expect a usable answer to continue with the "15".  Otherwise, how dos your suggested code say "next after ___"?

Comment: The 15 is just an example. You can see clearly what he wants with the sample 'query' he has given. He wants to select 'next' row of whatever 'post_IDs' his 'where' condition results in.

Comment: @RickJames Lol.. you know what, I didn't read the question these many times when I answered it... But after your comments I keep reading it again and again... :)