# Getting a previous record from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I figure out how I can get the next adid using this:

```
SELECT adid FROM table WHERE adid > $current_adid ORDER BY adid 
LIMIT 1
```

However, I am not sure how to get the previous adid. I tried changing `WHERE adid < $current_adid` but it didn't do the trick. What should I use to get a previous record from the SQL table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse more than just the comparison:

```
SELECT adid
FROM table
WHERE adid < $current_adid
ORDER BY adid DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` direction also needs to be reversed.

You could also replace these with:

```
SELECT MIN(adid)
FROM table
WHERE adid > $current_adid;

SELECT MAX(adid)
FROM table
WHERE adid < $current_adid;
```

The aggregation functions might make the logic clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I needed DESC there.