# SQL | Get next and previous id from current id in circularly

Tags: sql

I have following ids in my table.

```
[25,26,36]
```

I am able to fetch next and prev id easily if current id is 26 but I am not able to get next and prev id if current id 36. It is giving me a null record of next. Is there any possibility to give me id circularly. Here is my code which I use for next and prev id getting.

next record:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id > 26 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

previous record:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id < 26 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: what kind of dbms are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql)

Comment: @hotfix my question is different. As you sent a link which will not perfect solution which I want. I already mention my requirement in question.

Answer (score 1):

Use LAG/LEAD to get prev/next value unless it's not supported by sql engine.

```
SELECT *, 
       LAG(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS PreValue, 
       LEAD(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS NextValue
FROM (VALUES (25), (26), (36)) AS T(Id)
```

gives result

```
Id  PreValue    NextValue
25  NULL        26
26  25          36
36  26          NULL
```

and then fall back to max/min id when it's value

```
SELECT *,
    COALESCE(LAG(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id), MAX(Id) OVER()) AS PreValue, 
    COALESCE(LEAD(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id), MIN(Id) OVER()) AS NextValue
FROM (VALUES (25), (26), (36)) AS T(Id)
```

Note, the default partition is whole table. When you have a your own partition, keep them sync in four OVER clause.

Comment: Can I user this query in Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select a.id, CASE WHEN lag(a.id)over(order by a.v) is null then max(b.id) else lag(a.id)over(order by a.v) end as pr,
CASE WHEN  lead(a.id)over(order by a.v) is null then min(b.id) else lead(a.id)over(order by a.v) 
end as n 
from t1 a , t1 b
group by a.id,a.v
```

column 'v' is a primary key

Output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb72b/22

Comment: If current id is 25 then result will be next = 26 and prev = 36. You example does not display like I required

Comment: Can I use this query to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by moving the filter condition to the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id > 26 THEN id END) ASC,
         ID ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Similarly for the previous one:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id < 26 THEN id END) DESC,
         ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes, But I want the result in one query.

Comment: @jaydipsatvara . . . The question you have asked is:  "Is there any possibility to give me id circularly?"  This answers that question.  If you have a different question, I would suggest that you ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.