# MySQL get previous and next record when order by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `status_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `start_dt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `end_dt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `refreshed_dt` TIMESTAMP AS ((`start_dt` + interval ((to_days(`end_dt`) - to_days(`start_dt`)) / 2) day)) STORED,
    `job_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB 

CREATE TABLE `job_industry` (
    `job_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `industry_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`, `industry_id`),
     INDEX `job_industry_industry_id_foreign` (`industry_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `job_industry_industry_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`industry_id`) REFERENCES `industries` (`id`),
     CONSTRAINT `job_industry_job_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB 

INSERT INTO jobs (product_id, status_id, start_dt, end_dt, job_title)
VALUES (1, 4, "2019-07-28", "2019-08-28", "Financial Accountant"), 
       (1, 4, "2019-07-28", "2019-08-28", "Payroll Clerk"),
       (3, 4, "2019-07-28", "2019-08-28", "Management Accountant"),
       (1, 4, "2019-07-28", "2019-08-28", "Accounts Assistant"),
       (1, 4, "2019-07-28", "2019-08-28", "Auditor");

INSERT INTO job_industry (job_id, industry_id)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1);
```

I have the following query to return a paginated results set to return all jobs which are currently live and within the accountancy industry sector:

```
    select jobs.id,
           jobs.job_title
      from jobs 
inner join job_industry on job_industry.job_id = jobs.id
     where job_industry.industry_id in (1)
       and jobs.start_dt <= now() 
       and jobs.end_dt >= now()  
       and jobs.status_id = 4 
  group by jobs.id 
  order by CASE WHEN jobs.product_id = 3 AND jobs.refreshed_dt <= now() THEN 
            jobs.refreshed_dt 
              ELSE jobs.start_dt 
           END desc, jobs.id desc limit 10 offset 0
```

The order by clause in the above query uses the product_id and refreshed_dt to give a higher ranking to records - if the product_id is 3 then it's considered a premium listing and if its reached half way through it's listing period then we use the refreshed_dt to bump it up in the list. The refreshed_dt basically is the mid point between the start_dt and end_dt. We want to list the newest listing first.

The above query give me the following result set:

```
 id  | job_title       
----------------------
  3  | Management Accountant   <--- premium listing       
  5  | Auditor                 <--- previous
  4  | Accounts Assistant      <--- selected record
  2  | Payroll Clerk           <--- next
  1  | Financial Accountant
```

Now if I select record id 4, how do I get the previous and next records?

I've checked the following post [How to get next/previous record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446821/how-to-get-next-previous-record-in-mysql) but that only works if you're ordering by id.

This is my attempt to get previous record which returns record id 5 which is correct however if there were other premium records then i feel this query would fail:

```
 select MAX(jobs.id)
  from jobs 
inner join job_industry on job_industry.job_id = jobs.id
 where job_industry.industry_id in (1)
   and jobs.start_dt <= now() 
   and jobs.end_dt >= now()  
   and jobs.status_id = 4
   and jobs.id  > 4
order by CASE WHEN jobs.product_id = 3 AND jobs.refreshed_dt <= now() THEN 
            jobs.refreshed_dt 
              ELSE jobs.start_dt 
           END desc, jobs.id desc
```

And to get next record I have the following which return record id 1 which is incorrect:

```
select MIN(jobs.id)
  from jobs 
inner join job_industry on job_industry.job_id = jobs.id
 where job_industry.industry_id in (1)
   and jobs.start_dt <= now() 
   and jobs.end_dt >= now()  
   and jobs.status_id = 4 
   and jobs.id < 4
order by CASE WHEN jobs.product_id = 3 AND jobs.refreshed_dt <= now() THEN 
            jobs.refreshed_dt 
        ELSE jobs.start_dt  END desc, jobs.id desc
```

Some help to tackle this would be appreciated. Please note I've provided a minimal reproducible example above. Also i'm using  and limited to mysql version 5.7.17

Comment: How are you passing the command 'next' or 'previous'?

Comment: @Strawberry next or previous would include the id of the current record along with any search criteria to rebuild the original search query so in the above it would include industry ids.

Comment: It's just strange (to me) to be trying to do this kind of thing from a CLI, instead of some application-level code, but maybe I don't really follow

Comment: @Strawberry it would be done using Laravel. eg if it was a simply query order by id it would be something as follows: `$previous = Job::where('id', '<', $currentjob->id)->max('id');` Whatever application level code I'm using I need to figure out the query and then replicate it using what ever application ORM i'm using.